# React testing library, how to open a Collapse in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, antd, react-testing-library

I want to write a unit test that opens an antd. Collapse `<Panel />`

But no matter what combination of fireEvent or userEvent mouse actions I try, I cannot get React testing library to properly "click" on this antD component the same way a real user does.

Example code:

```
import { Collapse } from 'antd'
const { Panel } = Collapse

const Example = () => (
<Collapse>
  <Panel header="test" data-testid="testid">hello_world</Panel>
</Collapse>
)
```

and in my unit test:

I have tried the following combinations to open the Panel with the header "test"

```
const panel = screen.getByText('test')
userEvent.click(panel)

const result = screen.getByText('hello_world') // FAILED and never finds hello_world
```

```
const panel = screen.getByText('test')
userEvent.click(panel)

const result = await screen.findByText('hello_world') // FAILED and never finds hello_world
```

```
const panel = screen.getByText('test')
fireEvent.click(panel)

const result = await screen.findByText('hello_world') // FAILED and never finds hello_world
```

```
const panel = screen.getByText('test')
fireEvent.mouseDown(panel)

const result = await screen.findByText('hello_world') // FAILED and never finds hello_world
```

```
const panel = screen.getByText('test')
await act(async () => {
  fireEvent.mouseDown(panel)
})

const result = await screen.findByText('hello_world') // FAILED and never finds hello_world
```

```
const panel = screen.getByText('test')
await act(async () => {
  fireEvent.mouseDown(panel)
})

await waait(500) // using waait library, to force time to pass to see if it was that...

const result = await screen.findByText('hello_world') // FAILED and never finds hello_world
```

```
const panel = screen.getByTestId('testid')
fireEvent.click(panel) // FAILED, never finds anything with data-testid="testid"
// I guess antd did not bother passing the test-id to the component.

const result = await screen.findByText('hello_world')
```

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
                    <div
                      class="ant-collapse ant-collapse-icon-position-left css-14dabdk"
                    >
                      <div
                        class="ant-collapse-item"
                      >
                        <div
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          class="ant-collapse-header"
                          role="button"
                          tabindex="0"
                        >
                          test
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

I did also try to use `querySelector` on `container` to target `.ant-collapse-header`, `ant-collapse-item` or `.ant-collapse` with userEvent.click and fireEvent.mouseDown. But those didn't work either.

Why is this thing so difficult to open in a test .

Does anyone know how to open and antD Collapse component?

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/collapse/__tests__/index.test.js#L56 this is how they test it themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `user-event`, you can try:

```
await userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/test/i))
```

Or click the button, like:

```
await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"))
```

Then you can use `findByText` like:

```
expect(await screen.findByText(/hello_world/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
```

([Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-fz851z?file=/src/__tests__/hello.js:281-330))

Comment: Thank you so much. The first option of this worked for me :)

But I would love to know why it works differently from what I did? Why does `/test/i` work, and just "test" does not?

Comment: I think it should work with `"test"` too.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple example to simulate your issue.

What i did to get it working:

1. instead of screen, i use `getByText`, `queryByText` and `findByText` direct from the return of render, like `const { getByText, queryByText } = render(<Example />);`

* but you can use `screen`, not problem at all.

2. Your function test should be `async`, like:

```js
it("test", async () => { ... })
```

or

```js
test("test", async () => { ... })
```

3. To test the success of render 'Hello world', you can use `getByText` with `waitFor` or `findByText`, like below:

Code:

```js
describe("Test PANEL", () => {
  it("should PASS WITH QUERYBY - hello_world RENDERED after CLICKED", async () => {
    const { getByText, queryByText } = render(<Example />);

    const panel = getByText("test");

    fireEvent.click(panel);

    await waitFor(() => {
      const result = queryByText("hello_world");

      expect(result).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

  it("should PASS WITH FINDBY - hello_world RENDERED after CLICKED", async () => {
    const { getByText, findByText } = render(<Example />);

    const panel = getByText("test");

    fireEvent.click(panel);

    const result = await findByText("hello_world");

    expect(result).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

If you want to check if 'hello_world' is not rendered yet, i recommend you use `queryBy`, like this:

```js
describe("Test PANEL", () => {
  it("should PASS - hello_world NOT redenred before CLICKED", async () => {
    const { getByText, queryByText } = render(<Example />);

    const panel = getByText("test");

    expect(panel).toBeInTheDocument();

    await waitFor(() => {
      const result = queryByText("hello_world");

      expect(result).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

That´s because `queryBy` returns null if it doesnt find any Element, different than `findBy` and `getBy` -> both throws an error, as you can see in this [link](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/cheatsheet/#queries).